Vega lite deneb boxplot whisker width changed since update how to change whisker tick width
Previously my boxplots looked like this (note the width of the whiskers):

Since the recent update, they now look like this:

I don't want the whiskers extending beyond the width of the 'box' but I can't find how to adjust this as I didn't set the width in the old version so the default must have changed. How do I change my plots back to how they were?


You can configure the ticks property (here they are red and 100 pixels long)
{
  "height":300,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A horizontal box plot showing median and lower and upper quartiles of the distribution of body mass of penguins.",
  "data": {"url": "data/penguins.json"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "boxplot",
    "extent": 1.5,
    "median": {"color": "red"},
    "ticks": {"color":"red", "size":100} 
  },
  "encoding": { 
    "x": {
      "field": "Body Mass (g)",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false}
    }
  }
}

